# Getting the junk values in the URL - RESTAssured

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, rest-assured

I'm automating my GET API with RESTAssured, while I see the URI just before hitting the API, it is just normal, but when I add the query parameters, it adds junk values. I don't understand why adding query params does so, even when I print query params, it gives me proper value.

Here is my code snippet.

```
System.out.println("QUERY PARAMS"+queryParams);
        System.out.println(">>>>"+uri);
        Response response = RestAssured.given().config(RestAssured.config().sslConfig(this.getSslConfig())).filter(new AllureRestAssured()).contentType(appJsonContentType)
                .headers(requestHeader)
                .queryParams(queryParams)
                .when()
                .log()
                .all().get(uri);
```

And here is the logs -

```
QUERY PARAMS{amount=[2000.0], currency=[USD], date=[2022-04-01T00:00:00Z], id=[413275]}
>>>>https://www.example.com/amount/21345699
Request method: GET
Request URI:    https://www.example.com/amount/21345699?amount=2000.0&currency=USD&date=2022-04-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&id=413275
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this %3A in my URL. I tried

```
.all.get(URLEncoder.encode(uri, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

but it adds some localhost:8080 ahead of the URL. Can someone please help?

Comment: `RestAssured.urlEncodingEnabled = false;` might help you to stop URL encoding.

Answer (score 1):

These are URL encoded characters, as not all the character can be written directly to URL.

**%3A** is URL encoded sign "**:**" which I assume is separating fields of hour:minute:second in your parameters

Comment: Correct, that parameter gets as %3A which fails my test-cases. Can I add : instead of junk value?